# What does the statement, f2=${f%????} , mean?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to understand what the expression, `f2=${f%????}` means in a bash script.

I tried searching the web for some reference, but no luck finding something useful.

The code I'm using is:

```
for f in "$@"
do
f2=${f%????}
/usr/bin/openssl smime -in "$f" -verify -inform DER -noverify -out "$f2"
done
```

Comment: Have you read [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)? Especially the [EXPANSION](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's documented in the bash manual under [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter%word}`
> `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The *word* is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)). If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of *parameter*, then the result of the expansion is the value of *parameter* with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted. If *parameter* is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

In other words, `${f%????}` is the value of `$f` with the four last characters deleted.

You could also write `${f:0:-4}`, which is perhaps a bit clearer.

Comment: `${f%????}` is standard though. It's likely that the intent, though, is to remove a 3-letter extension and the `.` from the file name, in which case something more specific like `${f%.???}` would be preferable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. They have been very useful.